# To read a field with comma and quotes in csv where comma is delimiter - pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a record in my input csv file as,

```
"2017-11-01","2017-10-29","2017-11-04","4532491","","","","Natural States: "The Environmental Imagination" in Maine, Oregon, and the Nation","1000","Richard W. Judd"
```

When I read this csv in pyspark, the field `"Natural States: "The Environmental Imagination" in Maine, Oregon, and the Nation"` gets delimited as separate columns.

```
>>> df = spark.read.csv('file.csv')
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----+----+----+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------------+----+---------------+
|_c0       |_c1       |_c2       |_c3       |_c4 |_c5 |_c6 |_c7                                                      |_c8    |_c9             |_c10|_c11           |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----+----+----+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------------+----+---------------+
|2017-11-01|2017-10-29|2017-11-04| 4532491  |null|null|null|Natural States: "The Environmental Imagination" in Maine | Oregon| and the Nation |1000|Richard W. Judd|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----+----+----+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------------+----+---------------+
```

Any workaround apart from changing the delimiter in input file, as we can't change the input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `sparkContext` to read the files and `split` with multiple characters as `","` and then convert the `rdd` to `dataframe` as below

```
rdd = sc.textFile("file.csv")

def replaceFunc(words):
    result = []
    for word in words.split("\",\""):
        result.append(word.replace("\"", ""))
    return result

rdd.map(replaceFunc).toDF().show(1, False)
```

You should have following output

```
+----------+----------+----------+-------+---+---+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+---------------+
|_1        |_2        |_3        |_4     |_5 |_6 |_7 |_8                                                                            |_9  |_10            |
+----------+----------+----------+-------+---+---+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+---------------+
|2017-11-01|2017-10-29|2017-11-04|4532491|   |   |   |Natural States: The Environmental Imagination in Maine, Oregon, and the Nation|1000|Richard W. Judd|
+----------+----------+----------+-------+---+---+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This will likely work with `sep='","'` like:

```
spark.read.csv('file.csv', sep='","')
```

Comment: This will throw exception, delimiter cannot be more than one character.